# React-native cannot find images within same directory

Tags: image, react-native

I'm running a React Native app off of Xcode 10.3 and am attempting to load some icon images within a detailView screen, but for whatever reason React Native cannot see them. Whether I reload or rebuild the project (react-native run-ios), I receive the following error message:

`/Path/To/Project/src/components/DetailView.js`: The module `../images/call@2x.png` could not be found from `/Path/To/Project/src/components/DetailView.js`. Indeed, none of these files exist:

- `call@2x.png`
- `/Path/To/Project/src/images/call@2x.png/index(.native||.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)`

Here is my project's src directory:

[image]

And this image snippets from my **detailView.js**:

```
<ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
    <Image
        source={require('../images/background.jpg')}
        style={[theme.cardImageStyle, styles.image]}
    />
</ScrollView>

// ... More code here

<View style={styles.actionArea}>
    <TouchableOpacity>
        <Image
            source={require('../images/call@2x.png')}
            style={styles.actionImage}
        />
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <TouchableOpacity>
        <Image
            source={require('../images/sms@2x.png')}
            style={styles.actionImage}
        />
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <TouchableOpacity>
        <Image
            source={require('../images/email@2x.png')}
            style={styles.actionImage}
        />
    </TouchableOpacity>                
</View>
```

Here is my dependencies list from **package.json**:

```
"dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-native": "0.60.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-material-kit": "^0.5.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-navigation": "^3.11.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.5.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "^24.8.0",
    "eslint": "^6.1.0",
    "jest": "^24.8.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.55.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.6"
  },
```

The strange thing is that it has no trouble finding the background.jpg file, but I receive the same error message whether or not I change the name of the file I am looking for in the **require()** statement. I assume this is a problem with how RN or Xcode is building the project (Xcode is killing me right now, moving slower than 90s dialup).

All help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `@2x` from image path or try to make other files for different screen densities like below:

```
call@1x.png
call@2x.png
call@3x.png
```

Then just use

```
source={require('../images/call.png')
```

[DOCS](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images)

Answer (score 0):

remove @2x suffix from image path, they're reserved to provide images for different screen densities, just

```
source={require('../images/call.png')
```

from RN Images [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images)

```
the packager will bundle and serve the image corresponding to device's screen density.
If there is no image matching the screen density, the closest best option will be selected
```

You don't need to specify image corresponding size to device by yourself